# Distribution of $X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$ when $X$ is a matrix of iid normals

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I'm looking at a sparse linear regression model. For the problem I'm working on, I would like to show that there are many possible choices of the independent variables that are wrong but achieve low residual error. In particular, I have a setup of $Y=X\beta^*+W$, where $Y$ is $n\times 1$, $X$ is $n\times p$, with $X_{ij}$ distributed i.i.d. as $N(0,\sigma^2_x)$, and $W$ is i.i.d $N(0,\sigma^2_w)$. The OLS coefficient is $\beta_{OLS}=(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top Y$. This gives a predicted $\hat{Y}=X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top Y$. I want to consider the case that the true $\beta^*$ is actually 0, and bound the correlation between $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$, i.e. to see if $$\frac{Y\hat{Y}}{\lVert Y \rVert^2}$$ could be close to 1 even though $X$ is independent of $Y$.

I would therefore like to determine the distribution of $X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$ when $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix of i.i.d. normals, i.e. $X_{ij}$ are i.i.d. $N(0, \sigma^2)$ for all $i,j$. I know that in this case $X^\top X$ is distributed as a Wishart $W_p(\sigma^2 I_p,n)$ but I haven't got any further than this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you, I have added more context to the question.

Comment: Do you really need the distribution of the hat matrix ? The distribution of $\hat Y$ conditional on $X$ is multivariate normal.